# How does an Artificer obtain mundane objects for infusion/replication?

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting, artificer, artificer-infusions

I've been trying to figure out how to go about 'creating' the non-magical items needed so you can tinker them into trinkets, or infuse them into a replication of a magic item.

Things like Needles that would be needed for the tattoos, Sheets of Paper or a Book of them, Goggles, etc.

Also, I wouldn't mind learning how the devil basic Healing Kits are crafted, rules as written, if anyone can enlighten me please. Particularly in campaigns with little to no downtime or vendor access (a.k.a. *Curse of Strahd*)

Comment: I cannot seem to find a "Healing kit" in 5e. Did you mean the "Healer's Kit", or is it a homebrew item?

Comment: But I'm forgetting my manners! Welcome to the stack! You can learn more about how this site works by taking the [tour], or check out the [help] for other questions. You may also ask away in comments or in our [chat]. Happy stacking!

Answer (score 12):

### Find, craft or buy them

Some of these should be relatively common household items -- for example a needle, and you may obtain them in the course of normal adventuring.

#### Crafting

You can create mundane objects with the crafting downtime activity (p. 187 PHB) if you have the right tool proficiency.

> You can craft nonmagical objects, including adventuring
> equipment and works of art. You must be proficient
> with tools related to the object you are trying to create
> (typically artisan’s tools). You might also need access to
> special materials or locations necessary to create it

For a **Healer's Kit**, the rules do not state how to create one, neither in the PHB nor in *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, so that will in the end be up to your DM. It probably would be appropriate to have tools such as an Herbalism Kit, which states: *Also, proficiency with this kit is required to create antitoxin and potions of healing*, and while it does not explicitly mention the Healer's Kit, this seems to be a pretty good match -- someone must create them, they are not magical.

#### Buying

Even in *Curse of Strahd* there are merchants, so you will be able to buy some of these items.

> **Bilrath's Mercantile** in the Village of Barovia sells items from the Adventuring Gear table in the *Player's Handbook* with a price lower than 25 gp in the table, and for ten times the price.

> Arasek Stockyard in the Town of Vallaki does the same, but at five times the normal price.

Goggles are not listed in the equipment table, and judging from the price for a magnifying glass, also would cost more than 25 gp, so you may not be able to buy them anywhere in Barovia. But sheets of parchment should not be an issue. A book at 25 gp is unfortunately just out of reach. Needles are not listed but would be cheap judging from the Fishing Tackle that contains metal hooks. Of course, the DM always can decide if something is available for purchase, or not.

#### Non-mundane options

If you cannot find any of these objects and have no time to craft, and nobody to buy them from, then tough luck. You need some other, magical way to create them, like the *Fabricate* spell. Many of these however tend to be at least mid-level options, and may not be available at the start of the campaign to you. The College of Creation bard has a third level ability called Performance of Creation that allows them to create small, nonmagical item of limited monetary value, but it disappears again after proficiency bonus hours (the illusionist wizards level 14 Illusory Reality feature can create one, but that one disappears after a mere minute).

#### Discuss this between player and DM

Barring access to some of your class features by not making the required inputs available may well play into the feeling of dread and isolation *Curse of Strahd* aims to create, so it is possible that the DM will do that. However, **this should probably be discussed in advance**: it is no fun to have your features taken away without being warned, and a player then might prefer to play another class instead. Or the DM might add some of the missing base items to the adventure, maybe to be won or found as rewards to some side quest.

Comment: Just a note — simple goggles can be crafted from a bone: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_goggles — many different tools should allow to flatten bone and cut a slit into it. Irl wood, metal and stone tools works adequately. It shouldn't be a problem unless DM actively wants it to be.

Answer (score 7):

### Infusion components are up to the player & DM to work out.

I have an artificer in my game. I discussed this with the player, and we decided to hand-wave how he got any material parts needed for his infusions, in much the same way that we hand-wave when a Battlemaster Fighter trains to learn new maneuvers, when a sorcerer experiments with his power to learn to cast *fireball*, or when a wizard scribes the new spells she gains for free upon level-up. It seemed unfair to put extra costs or crafting time requirements on the artificer as compared to other classes simply because the artificer's flavor text is that they're making items rather than just conjuring things from the aether.

As part of learning the *replicate* infusion, the artificer obtains and prepares the material parts needed to implement it. We retcon that he has been working on preparing an item for infusion for days or weeks in his downtime or while traveling -- embroidering runes into the mouth of a bag that's destined to become an infused Bag of Holding, tattooing markings into a piece of leather that's supposed to be used to create a Cap of Water Breathing, and so on (often it's not even a retcon, since the player plans ahead pretty thoroughly in terms of what he's going to get, but I'd allow this even if he didn't). Essentially, the character has a pouch full of odds and ends that he buys and collects "off-screen", which only show up "on-screen" when he "completes" a project by gaining a level and learning the relevant infusion.

### Crafting rules from *Xanathar's Guide*

If crafting an item is actually important, or your players just want to make some mundane gear, *Xanathar's Guide* has rules for crafting items, though they're very basic -- you must pay half the gold cost of the item to buy materials, and then spend downtime to perform the crafting tasks at a rate of one work week (5 days at 8 hours per day) for each 50 GP cost. It says you can complete multiple items in the week if it costs less than 50 GP.

### Crafting with houserules

However, crafting is very often houseruled. Some common house rules include

- Ruling that it takes fewer days to craft less than 50 GP-worth of items
- Ruling that players can spend more than 8 hours per day on the task
  (possibly with a Constitution check to avoid gaining exhaustion from
  overwork) to speed things up if it's critical
- Creating a houserule that gives players a crafting check to
  determine how much progress is made, allowing a skilled character to
  finish an expensive item faster (but making progress less
  predictable).
- Allowing a skill check or short sidequest to substitute for the purchase of raw materials as the characters steal or scavenge parts, forage for special plants, or similar.

This last one is particularly useful in my opinion, because *usually* crafting is undesirable if the finished product is already available for purchase (as the monetary savings are rather small unless you're spending an awfully large amount of downtime on the task). It's rare to have raw materials available for purchase but not finished products. Usually if the players are talking about crafting equipment, it's because they're in some sort of survival scenario (like being stranded in an arctic wilderness or marooned on a tropical island) or in some other way isolated from external manufacturing (socially shunned, restricted from buying weapons, imprisoned), and gathering raw materials is going to be part of the adventure.

But following the standard crafting rules, a healer's kit costs 5gp, so you'd need to spend 25 silver on materials and spend a week on crafting (during which time you could craft ten of them).

If the DM allows you to reduce the crafting time to make fewer items, a 40 hour work-week that crafts ten kits suggests you can craft one kit in 4 hours once you have the materials, which is hardly even downtime at all. Still, as said, that depends on the DM allowing it, which isn't guaranteed.

Breaking down the time that way does not, of course, make sense in all cases, which is, I assume, why the rules don't make that a default option. Some manufacturing tasks require a certain amount of time but can be done in parallel while others are strictly serial. That is to say, if a skilled blacksmith with materials on hand and a hot forge could make two dozen knives in a week, it's entirely reasonable that he could make one knife in a couple hours, since he can really only work on one blade at a time; but drying leather armor or letting herbs steep in an alchemical solution will take the same time whether you make one item at a time or a dozen. It's up to the DM to decide whether to allow cutting the crafting time that way, and if so, which items can be crafted quickly and which can't.